# Identifying the type of an angular project?

Tags: angular, nativescript

Is there a way to tell if an angular project is a simple angular project, Nativescript project or an angular shared project?

Answer (score 0):

Check the package.json file. If it is a nativescript project you will see some of the nativescript packages installed. For example...

```
"@nativescript/theme": "~2.3.0",
"nativescript-angular": "~8.21.0",
```

Not sure what you are referring to as an angular shared project.

Comment: Adding tp Linda's answer, if the project has `"nativescript-schematics"` package in its package.json, or has *.web.ts files - it is a nativescript angular web shared project.

Comment: What I was talking about is more appropriately referred to as newscript angular web shared project I suppose. Not exactly clear on these terms yet. I will try testing all the answers given above. Thanks.